# Rdoc: How to document delegation?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

My class delegates a method to another object (which I'll call the helper object). I want to include documentation of that method in the delegating class, not just the delegated class. The programmer should not use the helper object, only the main object, so documenting in the helper object isn't very useful.

Consider this example. Rdoc outputs documentation about `Node#initialize` and `Helper#hello`. I want to have documentation about `Node#hello` as if it were just another method. Is there a way to do that?

```
require 'forwardable'

class Node
    extend Forwardable
    delegate %w(hello) => :@helper
    
    # Takes no params.
    def initialize
        @helper = Helper.new()
    end
end

class Helper
    
    # Outputs 'hello world'
    def hello
        puts 'hello world'
    end
end
```

-- update --

I tried yard. The yard command looks like this:

```
yardoc --no-private --protected app/**/*.rb -
```

I edited the ruby code to try to add documentation for Node#hello:

```
class Node
    extend Forwardable
    delegate %w(hello) => :@helper
    
    # Takes no params.
    def initialize
        @helper = Helper.new()
    end
    
    # @!method hello
    # Documentation for Node#hello
end
```

When I run yardoc, it seems to say that it processes three methods:

```
Files:           1
Modules:         0 (    0 undocumented)
Classes:         2 (    2 undocumented)
Constants:       0 (    0 undocumented)
Attributes:      0 (    0 undocumented)
Methods:         3 (    0 undocumented)
60.00% documented
```

If I don't have the `# @!method` directive then it says it only processes two methods:

```
Files:           1
Modules:         0 (    0 undocumented)
Classes:         2 (    2 undocumented)
Constants:       0 (    0 undocumented)
Attributes:      0 (    0 undocumented)
Methods:         2 (    0 undocumented)
50.00% documented
```

So it seems like it seems that documentation for `Node#hello`, but it doesn't appear in the actual documentation:

[image]

So I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: In Yard you use `# @!method hello` to overload and manually document methods - as far as I can RDoc does not have the equivilent [directive](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/RDoc/Markup.html#class-RDoc::Markup-label-Other+directives). You might want to look at the rails [guidelines](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/api_documentation_guidelines.html#dynamically-generated-methods) and source for examples.

Comment: @max: Please see my update to my question. I tried using yard the way you suggest, but it doesn't seem to quite work.

Comment: Hmm did any the longer format with a docustring as [detailed here](https://rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#method) work?

Comment: Ah hah! I figured it out. The `# @!method hello` tag has to be above a line of code. It doesn't work sitting by itself. I'll show a working example in my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On advice from @max, I switched to yard. Using yard, I can create method documentation without any actual method like this:

```
# @!method hello()
# Outputs "hello world"
delegate %w(hello) => :@helper
```

It's important to note that the documentation has to be above actual code. It won't work if it's by itself.